# Confusion over J-Link pinout

Tags: j-link

I have a SEGGER J-Link V9:

[image]
[image]

I have some confusion over two things:

- Do all J-Links have the same pinout? I can find different pinout diagrams online.
- Isn't pin 1 `VTREF` intended to just *sense* the voltage? On my J-Link, this pin can also provide power.

### 1. Do all J-Links have the same pinout?

I find several J-Link pinout diagrams online that don't match. For example (see https://wiki.segger.com/19-pin_JTAG/SWD_and_Trace_Connector):

[image]

And (see https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/technology/interface-description/):

[image]

So my first question is: do all J-Links have the same pinout - or do they differ?

### 2. What's going on with pin 1?

My second question is related to pin 1. This pin is labeled as `VTREF`. From the documentation I can find, this pin only *senses* the voltage. However, I noticed that it could even *power* my microcontroller board at 3V3. Isn't that weird? Or is something wrong with my J-Link (perhaps not a genuine model)?

### NOTE

I figured out I could enforce my J-Link to deliver 5V power on `pin 19`, like so:

[image]

Is something similar possible for `pin 1` (but for 3V3)? And for `pin 2` (also 3V3)?

Comment: That doesn't look like genuine Segger J-Link but a cheap chinese clone. Where did you buy it and how much you paid for it? It may only work with old or hacked drivers and might not even have a pinout comparable with an actual genuine J-Link.

Comment: That's a fake Segger clone without a doubt. Not that I'm judging - I bought one myself many years ago before my current job (I now have 3 genuine ones from work). But just remember that it might never work quite as well as the "real thing".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I bought this on a market in Shenzhen. I didn't know it was fake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. What you have does not look like a genuine Segger J-Link so whatever pinouts the genuine Segger J-Link probes have may not apply to your clone product.
1. On Segger web page, there are several different versions of J-Link probes with different pinouts as the different versions are for different purposes. So clearly the answer is no, they don't have same pinouts.
2. The Vtref is a reference voltage supply from the target to the JTAG adapter, so the JTAG adapter can communicate with the target using the same IO voltage. This allows the target to have whatever IO voltage it must have, such as 2.7V or something that varies if the voltage comes from say two AA batteries. If the JTAG adapter assumed e.g 3.3V logic levels, it could damage the MCU that runs at 2.7V.

Comment: Thanks for these clarifications. So a *real* J-Link would only sense the MCU voltage on pin 1, never deliver power through that pin - right? My fake J-Link seems to deliver power through that pin as well (it can power the whole board).

Comment: @K.Mulier Exactly. And these clone fake products can work very differently to the original product, and thus can do damage to your MCU board, or PC, when assumed it can be used like the original. I believe Segger drivers can detect fake products to some extent, maybe based on serial number, so I don't expect your latest official Segger drivers are even guaranteed to work with clone products properly, so even if they appear to work, a firmware update may brick your incompatible clone or driver update may stop working if it detects clone hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I bought this on a market in Shenzhen. I didn't know it was fake.

Comment: @K.Mulier What isn't fake on Shenzen market? If you get a $400 device with mere pennies, there is little doubt if it is real or fake. You always get what you pay for, even if you were not aware. The good side is, now you are aware and there is less chance you give your money to scammers. I don't know what you are going to use it for, but for example, a real Segger Jlink is $400 but just for programming and debugging STM32 MCUs, a genuine ST-Link is like $20 and clones (which I suggest not to buy of course because they are garbage) are around $2.

Answer (score 1):

It is stated on the label (in Chinese) that Pin 1 is internally connected to a 3.3V reference voltage. If external power supply is required, you can open the case and change the jumper position.